# HTML Canvas - Rotating a line from a specific point

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation, html5-canvas

I am having trouble rotating a line at a specific point (250,250) on HTML Canvas and I was wondering how people did it. I looked at the other answers and tried them but they did not fix my problem.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        function circles(){

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(250,250,6.35,0,2*Math.PI);
            context.stroke();

        }

        function lines(){
            var deg = 45;
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(250,250);
            context.lineTo(250,0);
            context.stroke();

            context.save();
            context.rotate(deg * Math.PI / 180);
            context.translate(20,-25);

    // This is the line I want to rotate
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(250,250);
            context.lineTo(250,0);
            context.stroke();

            //

            context.restore();

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0,250);
            context.lineTo(500,250);
            context.stroke();

        }

        circles();
        lines();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/athkcLyr/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there with the code that you have above. The key thing is that you need to `translate` the context to the point you want to rotate around, before calling `rotate`. You also need to `translate` the context back at the end.

Example with comments below:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function circles(){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(250,250,225.5,0,2*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(250,250,170,0,2*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(250,250,162,0,2*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(250,250,107,0,2*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(250,250,99,0,2*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(250,250,16,0,2*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(250,250,6.35,0,2*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();
}

function lines(){
    var deg = 45;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(250,250);
    context.lineTo(250,0);
    context.stroke();

    context.save();
    // Translate the context to the point we want to rotate around
    context.translate(250, 250);
    // Perform the rotation
    context.rotate(deg * Math.PI / 180);

    // Draw the line
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0,0);
    context.lineTo(-250,0);
    context.stroke();

    // Translate the context back to it's original position
    context.translate(-250, -250);
    context.restore();

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0,250);
    context.lineTo(500,250);
    context.stroke();

}

//Reference Lines
function refLines(){
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0,250);
    context.lineTo(500,250);
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(250,0);
    context.lineTo(250,500);
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0,0);
    context.lineTo(500,500);
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0,500);
    context.lineTo(500,0);
    context.stroke();
}

circles();
lines();
```

```css
section{
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```